# Karate API - ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: on upgrading to 0.9.0

Tags: karate

I am getting **ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: on upgrading to 0.9.0**. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my pom.xml and let me know if I am missing any dependency for latest version 0.9.0. It works fine on 
0.8.0. Here I am copying my working pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>io.testproject</groupId>
<artifactId>api-testing</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
<!--<version>0.9.0</version>-->
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <activemq.version>5.15.6</activemq.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <!--<karate.version>0.8.0</karate.version>-->
    <cucumber.reporting.version>3.8.0</cucumber.reporting.version>
    <!--<karate.version>0.9.0</karate.version>-->
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <!--<artifactId>karate-jersey</artifactId>-->
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-jersey -->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>karate-jersey</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>0.9.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.1</version>
        <!--<version>0.9.0</version>-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>0.9.0.RC1</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

On upgrading I am seeing issue with Karate UI runner that created and with Parallel execution setup.

```
  ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: mismatched input 
  '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
```

Comment: I remember parser will print the file name and line number as well to track  the exact feature caused the error? may be little more of karate log will also help to provide solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - this sounds very much like you have an empty file with a `*.feature` extension lying around. Karate is a little more stricter now. The log should tell you which feature to look at.

If this does not solve - yes this could be a parser bug. I need you to follow these instructions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Since this sounds like a serious bug, I'm willing to relax the rules and even if you provide a sample (minimal) feature file that can reproduce this - that would be great, and file an issue.

Comment: :This is coming when there a empty feature file in features folder.
line 1:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
15:27:14.719 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
15:27:14.728 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - not a valid feature file: classpath:features/products/Test.feature - mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}
java.lang.RuntimeException: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}.

Comment: However I have logged the issue https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/615